# Tabview vs. GridLayout vs. DockLayout

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-vue

I checked almost every demo application from the website, but nobody use tabview, only Gridlayout or docklayout for "tabbing" purposes. What is the benefit of the Gridlayout instead of tabview? Apart from the customize the background.

My point is to have a native tab look and feel on every page.

If I have page 1, page 2, page 3, all the page components should have the same tabview/GridLayout part, or I can move out the tabview section to an individual global component?

Apologize for the basic question.

Thanks!

Comment: Is this question about `NSTabView`?

Comment: I removed the label, apologize. I use Nativescript-vue, but I guessed it can be a general theoretical question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking for pure native look and feel, you would go with a TabView. Another advantage with TabView is lazy loading, it loads the page only when required.

You may go with GridLayout when you want to keep the TabView look similar on both iOS and Android. iOS by default uses Tabs at bottom and Androids places them at top. iOS would give you a More tab when the number of tab exceeds the available space, on Android it will be scrollable. These are by native, so if you want a customised common look and feel, then you could use GridLayout. Or still you could use the TabView and replace the TabBar with your own custom view, which is a bit complicated.

If you want the tabs on every page, then you should probably have a Frame inside each tab and load your pages there. So the TabBar remains same on every page. The same could be achieved with GridLayout, it's all about choices. I personally like sticking with the native look and feel of platform.

Comment: Thank you Manoj, appreciate your answer. It's clear now!